# Searching an external website from Wordpress search

Tags: wordpress, search, web, external

I'm trying to change the search functioanlity of a Wordpress website so it searches an external website instead.  While I've been able to change the form action to use the external websites URL, I haven't been able to get the right search results.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="et_search_outer">
            <div class="container et_search_form_container">
                <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="https://www.premierkitchenandbathgallery.com/search.htm?S1=">
                <?php
                    printf( '<input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" value="%2$s" name="s" title="%3$s" />',
                        esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),
                        get_search_query(),
                        esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )
                    );
                ?>
                </form>
                <span class="et_close_search_field"></span>
            </div>
```

As noted above, I'm attempting to search Premiere Kitchen & Bath using https://www.premierkitchenandbathgallery.com/search.htm?S1=

However, every search seems to fail, showing:

"We're Sorry!
Your search for "" 
did not match any results.."

So either the search term isn't being passed, or I'm not using the correct search string.  Any suggestions?  Here is the website I'm searching from, if you want to test - http://premierkitchen.solutioserver.com/  (use search bar in the menu)